# Python read from text file error

Tags: python-2.7

I'm writing a scrip for stress testing, the file i'm reading from is my input and it's a text file. Ideally I will be iterating the list of address to perform an stress test. The problem stems with the input, it's inefficient as a space won't be processed.

I'm having an odd glitch, my output works but it add odd spaces.

I've tried readlines(), but it yields the same result.

```
file = open('ip.txt', 'r') 
for line in file:
    print (line)

// Current OUTPUT
>> X.X.X.X
>> 
>> Y.Y.Y.Y
>> 

// Desired OUTPUT
>> OUTPUT:
>> X.X.X.X
>> Y.Y.Y.Y
```

thank You,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like that:

```
file = open('ip.txt', 'r').readlines()
for line in file:
   lines = line.rstrip()
   print lines
```

Comment: OMG UR AWESOME!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! WORKS PERFECTLY!

Comment: @UsualSuspect7 you can also accept my answer if that helped you =-)

Answer (score 0):

it works for deleting /n problems